# How to Simulate Paste with Electron Menu Bar App (Mac)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, clipboard, paste

I'm thinking of a creating a small menu bar paste app with Electron & Javascript, however I run into the wall of clipboard interaction.

What I want to do:

- User selects from menu bar certain saying (not copied, just a variable)
- As soon as user clicks selection from menu bar, full saying is pasted into whatever input box user has selected on their web browser (mainly Chrome)

- It is important to note that none of these sayings would be copied directly by user, they would be solid variables.

How would I go about create just a paste-function code?

Thanks!

Comment: take a look at [`clipborad`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/clipboard) api

Comment: @pergy Will take a look! Thanks.